# How much can a double Peltier stack cool to -30 C?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I need a -30 C freezer. Inside volume 5-30 l. I've seen videos of double Peltier stacks reaching -50 C with one Peltier running at 12V and the other at 5 or 7 V.

How big a freezer could such a stack cool to -30 C? Either a cube with up to, say, 5 cm thick expanded/extruded polystyrene (EPS/XPS) walls, or a wide neck Dewar with EPS/XPS lid.

Hot side cooling is probably with a waterblock, pump and heat exchanger with fan. T-hot ... does 40 C at 30 C ambient sound realistic?

I'm thinking of something like standard TEC1-12709 or -06 modules (12 V, 6/9 A, 40x40 mm), if they do the job. Local ones are kinda expensive (20-30 EUR). Aliexpress has some for a few USD. Are they ok?

I found some math to calculate Peltiers (https://www.overclockers.com/peltier-stacking/), but I was a bit overwhelmed (or maybe just lazy ;). EPS/EPX seems to have about 0.035 W/(m·K) thermal conductivity. I haven't found (or researched) Dewar thermal conductivity.

The freezer should reach -30 C in a finite time, e.g. 30 min, so remove a bit more heat at -30 C as is flowing in.

So, if you have experience I'd appreciate estimates. Calculations would be cool, too.

Compressor coolers or Sterling cryocoolers are probably not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: The units described won't work because they won't keep up with the heat leaking into the box. For the size and temps described, You'd want about 8" of the best insulating foam there is, and a sophisticated labyrinth closure to stop heat transfer along the closure interface. You are probably looking at a couple thousand dollars in parts to do this with peltier systems in anything more than trivial cooling capacity. A commercial freezer would be much cheaper both to buy and to operate. Best solution may be to put a single stage Peltier inside a cheap chest freezer that can pull down to -20C.

Comment: Peltier are very limited in terms of cooling capacity. You will only be able to cool small amount of heat or small volumes, anything bigger a freezer compressor is more suited. I doubt you will be able to cool a 5-30L volume to -30 with peltier, or by having extremely good insulation and long cooling time. I used to have a small 5L peltier fridge and it was cooling maybe 10°C below ambiant. Also care about thermal shock, Peltier do not like that and are easily destroyed.